# Object not visible in own class PHP 5 OOP

Tags: php, oop, visibility

I have a problem with a "Call to a member function on a non-object" - Error.
The field $other_class is not setable for future operations.
How can I fill and use the object $other_class? Thx.

```
    $myclass = new MyClass;

    $other_class = $myclass -> GetOther_Class();
    var_dump($other_class); //Works!

    echo $other_class; //Call to a member function on a non-object - Error

    class MyClass
    {
    private $other_class;

        function __construct()
        {
            $other_class =  new Other_Class; //Fill $other_class
            //I tried also 
            //$this -> other_class = new Other_Class;
        }

        public function GetOther_Class()
        {
            return $other_class;    
        }

        private function Generate()
        {
            $other_class -> SetTitle ("Hello"); 
        }

        public function __toString() 
        {
        $this->Generate();
        }


    }
```

Comment: always use `$this->` to access class members (unless they are static).

Comment: The error is not in the line you say. And after you've fixed that you get the next one. So take care: to properly understand an error you need to locate the line of code where it is actually raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're referencing `$other_class` and so will always be null or undefined when you try to return it in the Get methods.
When referencing a property of the current class, you need to prefix it with `$this->`:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $other_class;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->other_class =  new Other_Class; //Fill $other_class
        //I tried also 
        //$this -> other_class = new Other_Class;
    }

    public function GetOther_Class()
    {
        return $this->other_class;    
    }

    private function Generate()
    {
        $this->other_class -> SetTitle ("Hello"); 
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {
        $this->Generate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Im actually a C# Coder and this was so annoying. Cookies for MrCode and all the other good guys.

Comment: Ah yes, C# allows you to reference properties with no prefix so I can understand your confusion when coding PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because this following method is failing. When you `echo` something it calls the `__toString()` method.

```
    private function Generate()
    {
        $other_class -> SetTitle ("Hello"); 
    }
```

try changing this to

```
    private function Generate()
    {
        $this->other_class -> SetTitle ("Hello"); 
    }
```

and also in the constructor

```
   function __construct()
    {
        $this -> other_class = new Other_Class;
    }

    public function GetOther_Class()
    {
        return $this->other_class;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function GetOther_Class()
    {
        return $other_class;    
    }
```

in this part you return the local `$other_class` which does not exists you should return`$this->other_class` instead;